Getting "Illuminate\Database\QueryException" error after selecting MySQL as default database in Laravel
I recently tried configuring my Laravel application to use MySQL as the default database using VS Code Terminal. During the setup process, after selecting MySQL, I encountered the following prompt:
"Default database updated. Would you like to run the default migrations? (yes/no):"
After choosing "yes," I'm encountering an error:
Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'mydemoapp' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:813
    809▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    810▕                 );
    811▕             }
    812▕
  ➜ 813▕             throw new QueryException(
    814▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    815▕             );
    816▕         }
    817▕     }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:65
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=mydemoapp", "root", Object(SensitiveParameterValue), [])


  New to Laravel? Check out our bootcamp and documentation. Build something amazing!

Screenshot of the error
What did I try:
I attempted to configure my Laravel application to use MySQL as the default database. During the setup process, I selected MySQL as the default database option and agreed to run the default migrations when prompted.
I haven't tried anything else other than that because I'm just starting to learn laravel
What I am expecting:
I expected the migrations to run smoothly without any errors. However, after selecting "yes" to run the default migrations, I encountered an "Illuminate\Database\QueryException" error.
I'm seeking assistance in understanding why this error is occurring and how I can resolve it. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Just out of curiosity, have you tried to search for what this error could possibly mean and what solutions others have already came up with before asking this question?

First check if your mysql server is running or not?
Second check if you configured your mysql credentials in .env file?
